# A calculation of relative homology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Assume $M$ is a closed manifold, x is a point, x $\in$ $M$, how to calculate $H_n(M, M − x)$?

Comment: Use excision to reduce to a local calculation that doesn't depend on all of $M$.

Comment: Hint: if $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in the $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, then $H_i(M,M-x)=H_i(U,U-x)$ and $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional manifold. As Aaron suggests, by excision $M$ can be assumed to be the $n$-ball $D^n$, with $x=0$. Now, there is a homology long exact sequence
$$H_i(D^n\setminus\{0\})\to H_i(D^n)\to H_i(D^n,D^n\setminus\{0\})\to H_{i-1}(D^n\setminus\{0\})\to\cdots$$
Now $D^n$ is nullhomotopic so only has homology in degree $0$, and $D^n\setminus\{0\}\simeq S^{n-1}$ only has homology in degrees $0$ and $n-1$.

Comment: Your indices are in the wrong location.

Comment: my bad, fixed${}$

Comment: Oh, so now it’s a LES in *homology*!